# Entering multi language text in a html page

Tags: html

How can we enter another language other English in a text box in a html page
For example i have text box where we enter name and we provide different buttons

```
<html>
 <body>
   <form>
    NAME:<input type="text" name="name"/>
    <button>English</button>
    <button>Latin</button>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now based on the button clicked the text entering mode should be changed
How can i get this

Comment: What do you mean by text entering mode?

Comment: Why would you care about that? I mean, if the user is comfortable using Latin layout, they'd set it out and your browser would allow them to type in whatever layout they've chosen right?

Comment: it means here in this site only we are entering comments in english if i click latin or any other language i should be able to type in that language

Comment: You can always type in whatever language you want in whatever textbox. You just need the appropriate keyboard. Hello apparently: (привет, Olá, Hallå, 你好)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way out for this by changing browser settings... You can set your browser language and can accept required input language from keyboard... however this will be too limited... you can accept only those which browser... and this implementation will be browser specific...

Please refer [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688135.aspx) for further information.

i do not think there is way for this in the programming... either in java script (or) in HTML